# How to display message success or failed use respond on view ? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

My destory method on controller is like this :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try{
        if($this->product_service->destroy($id)){
            return $this->respond(['status' => 'success']);
        }else{
            return $this->respond(['status' => 'failed']);
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return $this->respondWithError();
    }
}
```

My view is like this :

```
@if (session('status')=='success')
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>Delete Success</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@elseif (session('status')=='failed')
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <ul>
            <li>Delete Failed</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

After the destroy method executed, it not display status success or failed

Why it does not work?

**UPDATE**

My controller extend ApiController

And in ApiController exist method like this :

```
public function respond($data, $headers=[])
{
    return response()->json($data,$this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually adding anything to the session anywhere.  You are also returning json responses so it's also hard to tell when your view is getting loaded exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use this package for that:

https://github.com/laracasts/flash

Please read the documentation there, it is very well explained.

OR

If you want to do that using custom code:

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   if($this->product_service->destroy($id)){
     return view('viewname', ['class' => 'success', 'message' => 'Delete Success']);
   } else{
     return view('viewname', ['class' => 'success', 'message' => 'Delete Failed']);
   }
}
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="alert alert-{{ $class }}">
     <ul>
       <li>{{ $message }}</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want use `$this->respond`. Not others. Does it can not?

Comment: NO, it can't,.. where you read about that method? Can you give URL?

Comment: My controller extend ApiController. In my ApiController exist method like this : `public function respond($data, $headers=[])
    {
        return response()->json($data,$this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call:

```
return \Redirect::back()->with('status', 'your status here...');
```

and that should be it.

Or you can use `Response:json` if you desire to return a `json object`, convenient with `AJAX` as followed:

```
return \Response::json(['status' => 'your status here...'], 200);
```

and then you can catch `status` on the view using `ajax` as followed:

```
errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
$.each(responseText, function(k, v){
 errorsHtml += '<li>' + v + '</li>';
});
errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
$("#feedback").append(errorsHtml);
```

Notice that you can pass any other data within `\Response::json` method:

```
return \Response::json(['status' => 'your status here...', 'data' => $data], 200);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data